# Angular JS 1.6 - Share object between ng-view and custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

(I'm new to AngularJS) I'm developing directives with isolated scope for reusable purposes but I'd like to share an object ("notified") between a custom directive inside a ng-view and a custom directives in index.html. Without routing "notified" is shared between the two directives, with ng-view notified is undefined in bottom-bar.

**index.html**

```
  <div ng-view></div>
  <bottom-bar notified="notified" bottom-showing="showBottomBar(ntf)" class-to-choose="chooseClass(ntf)"></bottom-bar>
```

**ng-view > org.html**

```
<org-list orgs = "orgs" notified="notified" name-filter="{{nameFilter}}" delete-orgs="deleteOrganization(organization)" add-org="addOrganization(organizationToAdd)" org-to-add="orgToAdd"></org-list>
```

**org-list directive**

```
organization
    .directive('orgList', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                deleteOrgs: "&",
                addOrg: "&",
                orgs: "=orgs",
                orgToAdd: "=orgToAdd",
                notified: "=notified",
                nameFilter: "@"
            },
            controller: 'OrgListController',
            templateUrl: 'organization/org-list.template.html'
        };
});
```

**bottom-bar directive**

```
bottom-bar
    .directive('bottomBar', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                notified: "=notified",
                classToChoose: "&",
                bottomShowing: "&"
            },
            controller: 'BottomBarController',
            templateUrl: 'bottom-bar/bottom-bar.template.html'
        };
    });
```

**bottom-bar template**

```
<div id="bottom-bar" ng-show="showBottomBar({ntf:notified})" ng-class="chooseClass({ntf:notified})" role="alert">
    <strong>Text</strong> Text.
</div>
```

**botton-bar controller, a function**

```
$scope.showBottomBar= function(notified){
    var ntf = notified["ntf"];
    console.log("showBottomBar() - notified: " + angular.toJson(ntf));    
    switch(ntf.value) {
        case 0:
            return false;
        case 1:
            return true;
        case 2:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: use angular.service

Comment: Ok, it works. Thank you!